# How do I make materials with transparent backgrounds in Blender 2.79?

Tags: texturing, transparency

[image]

This is pretty self explanitory. I want to make the glasses not have the ugly looking color, and just look like a sprite stretched over a model. But how do I do that in Blender 2.79?